# Replace Multiple Swatches - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cs6, swatches

I am trying to create a template for a wedding card with multiple color options.The design uses 4 colors in a custom swatch palette.

Is it possible for me to load a 'new 4-swatch palette' to replace the 'active 4 swatches', and change the colors in the document?

Thanks
Ng

Comment: How will this be displayed an used? Or is this a thing only for use inside Illustrator? Do you want to replace one colour with another? ("everything in this doc: change yellow to red") or do you just need to add a new palette?

Comment: Thanks. I need to replace a set of 4 colors, with 4 new colors. This will be used inside AI while changing the colors for a card to provide a new color theme. 

So yes, if I have set 1 (red, yellow, blue and green) as my first set I would like a new set 2 (Purple, Teal, Violet & Maroon) then Red=Purple, Yellow=Teal, Blue = Violet, Green=Maroon.

Thanks again.

Comment: So, something like this? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/illustrator-recolor-artwork-how-to-manually-choose-the-replacement-colours-fr

Answer (score 3):

Just select template for a wedding card and go to Edit Menu in Adobe Illustrator CS6.
Edit Menu -- Edit Colors -- Recolor Artwork 
here you can load a 'new 4-swatch palette' to replace the 'active 4 swatches', and change the colors in the document.